# What is /[Cc]at/ in perl?

Tags: python, perl

Could anyone tell me what the [Cc] in this code is called? I know what it does but I have no idea what it is called.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$sentence = "Big cat sat.";
$sentence =~ /[Cc]at/;

print "$`, $&, $'\n"; #prints Big, cat, sat.
```

Also does anyone know what is the perl equivalent of python 2.7's re.search? All I keep finding is something about python's replace being mutable and does not really say anything about search.

Comment: Regex / regular expression

Comment: In `/foo/`, `foo` is a regex. Thus, being inside of `//`, your `[Cc]` is regex syntax.

Comment: Just standard regex there, nothing perl specific.  That's not even PCRE or extended, that's valid regular expression in any flavor.  [] brackets match any character they enclosed.

Comment: ...and, well, the `=~` operator, which you're already using, is equivalent to Python's `re.search()`.

Comment: (I happen to consider building regular expressions into syntax rather than keeping them in the library a sin, but... well, it's Perl; if Larry had cared about what anyone else considered good practices in language design, it *wouldn't be* Perl.)

Comment: Charles Duffy, could you explain why you consider this such bad design?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: *Reductio ad absurdum* says that, if regular expressions are to be kept in a library then so also should all string, numeric, and boolean operations. I use regex patterns far more often than `*`, `**`, `^`, `<<`, `xor`, and (bitwise) `&` etc. so, if you consider that to be a criterion, then there are many other parts of the language that should be jettisoned first. I would guess that you're one of the group who  say *There's More Than One Way To Do It* is also a sin, and there should be exactly one correct solution to everything?

Comment: @Borodin, ideally, yes, your string, numeric, boolean, and logic operations are also functions. Making `&&` and `||` functions while preserving short-circuiting behavior can be done as well, if one has macros. I'm a LISPer -- we're purists. :)

Comment: @Borodin, ...and yes, I do also hold that TIMTOWTDI is the precise opposite of a reasonable guideline. If everyone has their own personal style, you end up in a world where people know the half of the language they personally use, and can't read other peoples' code without stopping and puzzling.

Comment: @skyler, because syntax provides a namespace that has critical characteristics not shared by anything else. (1) - If you don't know the core syntax, and how the various forms interact with each other, you don't know the language. (2) - Core syntax cannot be changed without breaking backwards compatibility. (3) - Core syntax cannot be selected between or versioned. Given those three axioms, the reasons for keeping core syntax as small as possible should be obvious on their face.

Comment: @skyler, ...put regexes in a library, and someone can decide whether they want full PCREs with powerful constructs and potential backtracking, or a Thompson NFA implementation with constant-time performance guarantees; and the folks publishing the Thompson NFA implementation have full parity with the PCRE one. Elevate one version into syntax, and the decision on which to use if any is no longer orthogonal to the language itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks for the response, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 7):

Bracketed groups of characters are called [**character classes**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) or **character sets**.

Regular expressions have a [simple formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) with just a few operations. One of these operations is [**alternation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternation_%28formal_language_theory%29). Alternations allow you to match against the union of two sets of strings. Character sets are syntax for an alternation over a group of single character strings. More commonly when we talk about [alternations in regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) we are referring to the use of the vertical bar `|` which matches the union of the expressions on either side of the bar.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand the close votes, but you've made the mistake of asking more than one question!

It's hard to know what's tripping you up, but this may help

The pattern `/[Cc]at/` as a whole is a *regular expression*, *regexp* or *regex*, while the particular component `[Cc]` is called a *character class*, which matches any of a set of characters; in this case an upper or lower-case C character. It's documented in the Python documentation for [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), which calls it just a "set of characters", and speaks about things like `\d` (numeric digits) and `\w` ("word" characters) as character classes. In Perl, the square-bracket construct is also a character class

The documentation for [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) on the same page is fairly simple, and you seem to have used its Perl equivalent in your code so I don't understand the problem you're having

In Python,

```
object = re.search(pattern, string)
```

checks for the occurrence of *pattern* anywhere in *string* and sets `object` to a [*match object*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) if one is found, or `None` otherwise

This is the same in Perl as using the *binding operator* `=~` like this

```
my $result = $string =~ /pattern/
```

which sets `$result` to a *true* value if a match was found, or *false* otherwise

Take a look at the Python documentation for [search() vs. match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

`re.match` is identical to `re.search`, except that the match must occur at the very start of the string